# Creating Smooth Animations

Tags: animation, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the best way to create animations when doing Android development?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18003/whats-the-best-way-to-create-animations-when-doing-android-development)
>   [What animation technique is used in ‘Dont Starve’?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/44319/what-animation-technique-is-used-in-dont-starve)

I've always admired Zeptolab for their smooth in game animations. Zeptolab has created both Cut the Rope and now Pudding Monsters.

I'm wonder how you're able to get animations this smooth? Are these sprite sheets? Are they actual 3D models?

Here's a video of their latest game:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rV1dlN-dbJQ

If you get to the game play you'll see how the guys are constantly wiggling and it's so smooth. You also saw this in the monster guy in Cut the Rope.

I'm just wanting some insight into how this is done. Like what tools they may be using.

Thanks

Comment: They look to me like multiple layers of animated 2D vector objects, so it's possible that they're rendered from huge spritesheets to avoid aliasing. But I have zero evidence of that.

Comment: I tend to feel that "How was <x> done in game <y>" questions must be off-topic for the site, based on the [FAQ](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)'s guideline: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on **actual problems that you face**."  If the question was "How can I make smooth animations", then that'd be fine.  But just asking how somebody else did it.. I don't know that it's really answerable by anyone who didn't actually work on the specifically named game.  And even in that case, I don't know that it's really useful knowledge worthy to be archived forever.